# Time out a process with context manager in python

Tags: python, python-multithreading, contextmanager

I am trying to write a context manager to timeout a process, and I have following:

```py
import threading
import _thread
import time
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def raise_timeout(timeout):
    timer = threading.Timer(timeout, _thread.interrupt_main)
    timer.start()

    try:
        yield
    except:
        print(f"timeout after {timeout} seconds")
        raise
    finally:
        timer.cancel()

with raise_timeout(1):
    time.sleep(5)
```

the problem is when the time out is reached, it still waits for the `time.sleep(5)` to finish before the exception is raised. when I run the script I waited for 5 seconds before getting the following output in the terminal:

```
> timeout after 1 seconds Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "scratch1.py",
> line xx, in <module>
>     time.sleep(5) KeyboardInterrupt
```

but if I run the timer directly as below I got the exception right after the 1 second timeout.

```py
timer = threading.Timer(1, _thread.interrupt_main)
timer.start()
```

I just wonder how the process in the with statement can block the exception till it finishes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that your `Timer` solution is not functioning as `time.sleep` doesn't get killed when calling `_thread.interrupt_main()`.

The [`_thread`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/_thread.html) docs make a suggestion about how it functions:

> Threads interact strangely with interrupts: the `KeyboardInterrupt` exception will be received by an arbitrary thread. (When the signal module is available, interrupts always go to the main thread.)

Though an [issue on Python's bug tracker](https://bugs.python.org/issue29926) suggests the documentation for `_thread.interrupt_main()` is imprecise.

It should be noted, that substituting in a long running process instead of `time.sleep` your context manager works as expected.

Try:

```py
with raise_timeout(1):
    for _ in range(1_000_000_000):
        pass
```

and it will raise a `KeyboardInterrupt`

---

If portability is not an issue, here's a solution using [`signal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html) that is only available on Unix as it uses `SIGALARM`.

```py
import signal
import time
from contextlib import contextmanager

class TimeOutException(Exception):
    pass

@contextmanager
def raise_timeout(timeout):
    def _handler(signum, frame):
        raise TimeOutException()
    signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, _handler)
    signal.alarm(timeout)

    try:
        yield
    except TimeOutException:
        print(f"Timeout after {timeout} seconds")
        raise
    finally:
        signal.alarm(0)

with raise_timeout(1):
    time.sleep(2)
```

Which will raise a `TimeOutException`

Comment: portability is exactly the reason i didn't use signal.... but good to know that this is only an issue with `time.sleep`